# Prove or disprove that $A[x]/I$ is an integral domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, roots-of-unity, integral-domain

> Let $A = \Bbb Z [\omega]$ be the subring of complex numbers where $\omega$ is a non-real $6$-th root of unity. In the polynomial ring $A[x],$ let $I$ be the ideal generated by $(x^2+x+1).$ Prove or disprove that $A[x]/I$ is an integral domain.

Let $\omega_1, \omega_1^2$ be the primitive cube root of unity. Let $\overline A(x) = (x - \omega_1) + \left \langle x^2 + x + 1 \right \rangle$ and $\overline B(x) = (x - \omega_1^2) + \left \langle x^2 + x + 1 \right \rangle.$ Then $\overline A(x), \overline B (x)$ are two non-zero elements of $A[x]/I$ whose product is zero. Hence $A[x]/I$ is not an integral domain. Can it be proved in a diffrent way i.e. by the help of Chinese remainder theorem for rings?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think $A[x] / I \cong \left ( A[x] / \left \langle x - \omega_1 \right \rangle \right ) \times \left ( A[x] / \left \langle x - \omega_1^2 \right \rangle \right ) \cong A \times A.$ But $A \times A$ is not an integral domain as $(1,0) \cdot (0,1) = (0,0).$

Comment: Since $(x - w_1)$ and $(x - \omega^2)$ are co-primes it follows by Bezout's theorem that there exist $p(x), q(x) \in A[x]$ such that $p(x) (x - \omega_1) + q(x) (x - \omega_1^2) = 1.$ So we have $$1 \in \left \langle x - \omega_1 \right \rangle + \left \langle x - \omega_1^2 \right \rangle \implies  \left \langle x - \omega_1 \right \rangle + \left \langle x - \omega_1^2 \right \rangle = A[x].$$ Now we can apply Chinese remainder theorem as I mentioned in my above comment. Am I right?